# PHP post_max_size limit with serialized input

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatables and have checkbox against each row. There is a select all function that marks all the checkboxes in the list. I have got all the checked inputs in serialized form, I created a new form with a hidden field. I made the value of this hidden field the serialized string.

Now my question is: In future If I'll be having thousand of rows in my datatable, is it gonna affect my functionality. Is there a limit of value that we can give to input?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a limit on input value and is defined under **max_input_vars**,

> max_input_vars    1000    PHP_INI_PERDIR  Available since PHP 5.3.9.

[Official Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)

Answer (score 0):

Most webhosting providers will allow you to change (some) php settings via .htaccess files. Here is what you need to add:

```
php_value post_max_size 52428800 # 50MB
php_value upload_max_filesize 52428800 # 50MB
php_value max_execution_time 300 # 5 minutes
```

After making these changes to .htaccess file, double check using:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Look at the local values.

**Note:**

> This works if PHP runs as an APache module. If your web hosting setup
>   is different, you must ask them about how to do this. AFAIK, it is
>   possible to put (some of) the settings in a php.ini file and upload to
>   the root directory of your website but depends on how PHP and Apache
>   are setup.